# Passing Datatable Between ASPX Pages

Tags: asp.net, datatable

My problem is, i have to pass an user specific Datatable between all of my webpages in the application.

First Solution:

When User Login i get the information specific to the user then put it in a session variable and pass it over in every other pages.

The Size of the DataTable May be differ for each user and cannot predict the concurrent user request.

IF 50 concurrent users are having 25 rows of data then(50 x 25 = 1250 Rows), I am worrying about the memory that occupied which causes performance issue.

Second Solution:

When User Login, I pass user name and Password details to each page and i get the datatable from SQL Stored Procedure.

I feel like this also having performance issues.

Is there anyother best way i could possible try out for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

If your feeling memory issue accroding to your database size that your retrieving than you can take help of Caching. You can store your data once to load from database to Cache object that you use that Cache object where ever you need on any page

Comment: I am not clear what you 've mention for caching so i am asking you another question for clarify myself.... Is Cache available to User Specific? If you want me to use cache object for retrieve all values from database then query from cache object to user specific then it would be tedious for my application :)